# Differential equation proving identity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I consider the differential equation $ u'(t)+a(t)\cdot u(t)=b(t) $.
I want to show that $$ u(t)=\underbrace{\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\ ds\right )\cdot c}_{=f(t)}+\underbrace{\int_{t_0}^t \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(s)\ ds}_{=g(t)} \ ,\quad c\in \mathbb{R}$$
solves this differential equation.

My attemp:

$$ \begin{align}f'(t)&=\frac {d}{dt}\left(\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\ ds\right )\cdot c \right)\\&=-c\cdot a(t)\cdot \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\ ds\right )\\[20pt]g'(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{t_0}^t \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(s)\ ds\right)\\&=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{d}{dt}\left(\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(s)\ \right)ds\\&=\int_{t_0}^t \left[\frac{d}{dt}\left(\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\right)\cdot b(s)+\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b'(t)\ \right]ds\\&=\int_{t_0}^t \left[-a(t)\cdot \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right)\cdot b(s)+\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b'(t)\ \right]ds \\&=\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot \int_{t_0}^t (-a(t)\cdot b(s)+b'(t))\ ds\\&=\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot\left(b(t)-a(t)\cdot \int_{t_0}^t b(s)\ ds\right)\\[20pt]a(t)\cdot u(t)&=a(t)\cdot \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\ ds\right )\cdot c+a(t)\cdot \int_{t_0}^t \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(s)\ ds\\&=a(t)\cdot \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\ ds\right )\cdot c+a(t)\cdot \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot \int_{t_0}^t b(s)\ ds\\[20pt]u'(t)+a(t)\cdot u(t)&=f'(t)+g'(t)+a(t)\cdot u(t)\\&=\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot\left(b(t)-a(t)\cdot \int_{t_0}^t b(s)\ ds\right)+a(t)\cdot \exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot \int_{t_0}^t b(s)\ ds\\&=\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(t)\end{align}$$.

I don't see what went wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You got the  solution wrong. The correct solution is  $$ u(t)=\underbrace{\exp \left( -\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\ ds\right )\cdot c}_{=f(t)}+e^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(r)\ dr}\underbrace{\int_{t_0}^t \exp \left( \int_{t_0}^s a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(s)\ ds}_{=g(t)} \ ,\quad c\in \mathbb{R}$$

Use product rule to write down $g'(t)$ and you will see that $u'(t)+a(t)u(t)=b(t)$.

Comment: I get problems to calculate $ g'(t) $. I'm totally confused by $ b(s) $. $$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{t_0}^t \exp \left( \int_{t_0}^s a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(s)\ ds \right)\\=\int_{t_0}^t \frac{d}{dt}\left(\exp \left( \int_{t_0}^s a(r)\ dr\right )\cdot b(s)\ \right)ds $$